# How to create custom one hot encoding by keywords on text sequences

Tags: python, vector, text, nlp

I have a list of text sequences that look like this:

```html
    sequences = [
    ['okay', ''],
    ['ahead', 'fred', ''],
    ['i', 'dont', 'remember', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'go', ''],
    ['um', ''],
    ['let', 'me', 'think', '']
]
```

I want to create a one hot vector for each sequence that counts the occurrence of certain words from a list. The list of words to look for is here:

```
    keywords = ['i', 'you', 'we']
```

Ultimately, I want to loop through each text sequence and return the following (where 0 means the keyword was not present and 1 means it was):

```
    seq_to_vec = [
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0],
        [1,1,0],
        [0,0,0],
        [0,0,0]
    ]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a fairly simple (well, simple for Python) list comprehension:

```
[[1 if keyword in sequence else 0 for keyword in keywords] for sequence in sequences]
```

The following complete program shows this in action:

```
sequences = [
    ['okay', ''],
    ['ahead', 'fred', ''],
    ['i', 'dont', 'remember', 'you', 'want', 'to', 'go', ''],
    ['um', ''],
    ['let', 'me', 'think', '']
]
keywords = ['i', 'you', 'we']

print([[1 if keyword in sequence else 0 for keyword in keywords] for sequence in sequences])
```

As expected, the output is:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Note that this is based on your "where 0 means the keyword was not present and 1 means it was" text, meaning it doesn't cater for the same word appearing twice. If you duplicate `i` in the third sequence, you'll still only get `1` in that position rather than `2`.

If you want an actual *count* rather than a `0/1` presence indicator (based on your "counts the occurrence" text), it's a little more complex, but still using the same basic idea:

```
[[sum([1 if keyword == word else 0 for word in sequence]) for keyword in keywords] for sequence in sequences]
```

Duplicating `i` in the third sequence will then deliver you:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Out of curiousity, how would you edit this so that instead of yielding a 0 or 1, it yielded the count of keywords in that sequence?  For example, if 'i' occurred twice in the 3rd (2nd in python) sequence, the resulting vector would be [2,1,0].

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, using list comprehension and the list [count()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method

```
def sequences_to_num_of_ocuerences_vector(sequences, keywords):
    return [[seq.count(k) for k in keywords] for seq in sequences]
```